# Is it possible to add date picker in checkout magento 2

Tags: checkout, checkout-page, guest-checkout, datepicker

I been trying to figure out how to add date picker in checkout. I can add date picker by plugin but I am not sure if that is correct way. I was expecting this to be done through knockout js but I couldn’t get anywhere with it 
Is it possible I could get the value of date picker to Database

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately modifying the checkout is one of the hardest things to achieve. You need to so several things.

Take a look at this extension

https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate

Date field too.

Or perhaps mine as a start

https://github.com/DominicWatts/OrderComment

It's a text field but demonstrates what you need to do to get it to save